# How to pass a parameter to a usercontrol in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a usercontroll which accepts some parameter and I need to insert this usercontrol in repeater and pass a parameter from List<> to each one, I'm doing it like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="winnersRepeater" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <uc:myControl ID="myControl" NodeId="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>" runat="server" />        
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I do binding in PageLoad:

```
List<Winner> winners = new List<Winner>();
//...
winnersRepeater.DataSource = winners;
winnersRepeater.DataBind();
```

It doesn't work, I'm getting `Error creating usercontrol... The server tag is not well formed.`

How can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is with quotes - you are using double quotes both to open and close the NodeId property here, and to enclose the string in the expression. You should use single quotes in one place, and double in the other.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I tried to escape them but that didn't work so I thought the problem somewhere in page lifecycle. This works `NodeId='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>'` but the other way round doesn't. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the ItemDataBound event of the Repeater. In your handler you should be able to do FindControl("myControl") and pass to it the NodeId value without having to declare it in the mark-up.

Comment: Thanks ddc, the other solution looks simpler:)